# Returning after VPN tunnel is up

Tags: scripts, openvpn

I have a working TeamCity setup for my projects on my local network using local resources like svn, web servers and database servers. Now I want to be able to open a vpn tunnel to another network and then run a build from remote resources.

I have the tunnel working using openvpn:

```
sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn
```

My problem is that once the tunnel is open I want to be able to run the next step but the openvpn process needs to be running.

Is there a way to make a "start script" that doesn't return until the tunnel is up and if so, how would I kill it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start :

`sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn --daemon --writepid /var/run/openvpn-MyTunnel.pid`

To kill :

`sudo kill $(cat /var/run/openvpn-MyTunnel.pid); sudo rm /var/run/openvpn-MyTunnel.pid`

Openvpn has also a management interface that you can use to remote control  the openvpn daemon (see the **--management** option in   [openvpn manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man8/openvpn.8.html)).

Comment: I have some password to enter too. Can I add that in too?

Comment: @Asken Is it the password for the sudo command or a password so openvpn establish tunnel with the remote host ?

Comment: For the tunnel. I basically want to create an upstart script for it

Comment: @Asken  if it is user/password authentication : --auth-user-pass <filename> if it is a  key passphrase  : --askpass <filename> (see the manpage).  Both options can be defined in the conf file (just remove the -- )